# Is there a way to insert line-breaks in a tcbox within a forest environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, tcolorbox, nodes, forest

I am trying to get line breaks in a tcolorbox object whose width is limited to the width of the text therein (or to the width of the forest node it is inside).

This is standardly done via \tcbox[tikznode]{asdf//asdf}, but this produces an error within a forest environment.

Is there a way for me to produce the desired effect?

Thank you for your time and help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbox[tikznode]{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}

\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [C]]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [C\\\tcbox{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}]]
\end{forest}

%%%%% example below causes error
\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [C\\\tcbox[tikznode]{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE results for working portion]

The image above shows what the code produces when the line that causes the error is commented out.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets (`[` and `]`) in `\tcbox[...]{..}` breaks the syntax of a `forest` tree, when default bracket representation settings (see `texdoc forest`, sec. 3.3) are in use. Wrapping the whole `forest` node in a pair of braces (`{` and `}`) works.

```tex
\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [{C\\\tcbox[tikznode]{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}}]]
\end{forest}
```

[image]

But this only eliminates the errors, you will see an empty `\tcbox` in the result. My guess is that it's caused by nesting `tikzpicture`s, which is not officially supported from `tikz`'s view. `tikznode` makes the `\tcbox` a `tikzpicture`, and `forest` typesets each of its node in a separate `tikzpicture`. Hence the nesting.

Fortunately, `tcolorbox` provides a `varwidth upper` option which allows multi-line `\tcbox` content *and* avoids nested `tikzpicture`s.

Finally, you can define a costumed `\tcbox` which calls `varwidth upper` by default.

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
%\usepackage{tikz} % already loaded by `forest`
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth} % for tcolorbox option `varwidth upper`

\newtcbox{\forestTcbox}{varwidth upper}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [{C\\\tcbox[varwidth upper]{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}}]]
\end{forest}
%
\begin{forest}
    [A [B] [{C\\\forestTcbox{asdf\\asdf\\asdf}}]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `tcolorbox` at all. The `forest` package allows you to make the box with your own specifications:

[image]

I made the box using `forestset` in the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}

\forestset{mybox/.style={draw=black!75, line width=1.5pt, rounded corners, no edge, fill=gray!10, minimum size=1.7cm, before drawing tree={y+=5mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [A [B, fit=band] [C[asdf\\asdf\\asdf, mybox]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer worked perfectly, too.